# Any app for finding memory usage in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks, memory-management

Is there any app for monitoring memory usage while running an app in ipad, just like instruments. I am not able to track the memory usage with instruments from ipad. I found an application named console. It will show all log files.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for, but you can check XSysInfo app http://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/id354129029?mt=8

Hope this'll help

Comment: AppSwitch is a similar one: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appswitch/id398317469?mt=8

Answer (score 2):

Go to this link: (and memory management is about code not about device)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial